# Sharing on Linkedin Android

Tags: java, android, linkedin-api

I want to share text on Linkedin for that i have used below code

```
    public class ShareWithLinkedIn extends Activity {
public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_COUSUMER_KEY";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_SECRET_KEY";
public static final String APP_NAME = "SharePhotoImage";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN = "oauth_token";
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER = "oauth_verifier";
static final String OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM = "oauth_problem";
static final String OAUTH_PREF = "AppPreferences";
static final String PREF_TOKEN = "linkedin_token";
static final String PREF_TOKENSECRET = "linkedin_token_secret";
static final String PREF_REQTOKENSECRET = "linkedin_request_token_secret";

final LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
LinkedInApiClient client;

TextView tv = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tv = new TextView(this);
    setContentView(tv);
    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    final String token = pref.getString(PREF_TOKEN, null);
    final String tokenSecret = pref.getString(PREF_TOKENSECRET, null);
    if (token == null || tokenSecret == null) {
        startAutheniticate();
    } else {
        LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = new LinkedInAccessToken(token, tokenSecret);
        showCurrentUser(accessToken);
    }
}// end method

void startAutheniticate() {
    new Thread() {// added because this will make code work on post API 10
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final LinkedInRequestToken liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
            final String uri = liToken.getAuthorizationUrl();
            final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, liToken.getTokenSecret());
            editor.commit();
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }.start();
}// end method

void finishAuthenticate(final Uri uri) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (uri != null && uri.getScheme().equals(OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
                final String problem = uri.getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_PROBLEM);
                if (problem == null) {
                    final SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
                    final String request_token_secret = pref.getString(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET, null);
                    final String query_token = uri.getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_TOKEN);
                    final LinkedInRequestToken request_token = new LinkedInRequestToken(query_token, request_token_secret);
                    final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(request_token, uri.getQueryParameter(OAUTH_QUERY_VERIFIER));
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                    editor.putString(PREF_TOKENSECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                    editor.remove(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET);
                    editor.commit();
                    showCurrentUser(accessToken);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application down due OAuth problem: " + problem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
}// end method

void clearTokens() {
    getSharedPreferences(OAUTH_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(PREF_TOKEN).remove(PREF_TOKENSECRET).remove(PREF_REQTOKENSECRET).commit();
}// end method

void showCurrentUser(final LinkedInAccessToken accessToken) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            final LinkedInApiClient client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
            try {
                final Person p = client.getProfileForCurrentUser();
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // here you can do client API calls ...
                // client.postComment(arg0, arg1);
                // client.updateCurrentStatus(arg0);
                // or any other API call (this sample only check for current
                // user
                // and shows it in TextView)
                // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {// updating UI thread from
                                                // different thread not a
                                                // good idea...
                    public void run() {
                        tv.setText(p.getLastName() + ", " + p.getFirstName());
                    }
                });
                // or use Toast
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "Lastname:: "+p.getLastName() + ", First name: " +
                // p.getFirstName(), 1).show();
            } catch (LinkedInApiClientException ex) {
                clearTokens();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Application down due LinkedInApiClientException: " + ex.getMessage() + " Authokens cleared - try run application again.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            Looper.loop();
        }
    }.start();
}// end method

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    finishAuthenticate(intent.getData());
}// end method
```

}// end class

it shows me login and allow screen which is looking like below when i click that button again same screen will be shown,,  but i want like when (i click on that button it should share a text with image url)...

can any body help me to solve this problem

[image]

Comment: for posting Share on Linkedin you will need to also request `rw_nus` permission. plz see  [Linkedin Share API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/share-api)

Comment: can you give me example how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

By below code i have done

```
    public class ShareInLinkedIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private LinkedInOAuthService oAuthService;
private LinkedInApiClientFactory factory;
private LinkedInRequestToken liToken;
private LinkedInApiClient client;
public static final String LINKEDIN_PREF = "GamePrefs";

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.linkedin);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    oAuthService = LinkedInOAuthServiceFactory.getInstance().createLinkedInOAuthService(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET, Constants.SCOPE_PARAMS);
    System.out.println("oAuthService : " + oAuthService);

    factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);

    liToken = oAuthService.getOAuthRequestToken(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);
    System.out.println("onCreate:linktoURL : " + liToken.getAuthorizationUrl());
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(liToken.getAuthorizationUrl()));
    startActivity(i);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    try {
        linkedInImport(intent);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void linkedInImport(Intent intent) {
    String verifier = intent.getData().getQueryParameter("oauth_verifier");
    System.out.println("liToken " + liToken);
    System.out.println("verifier " + verifier);

    LinkedInAccessToken accessToken = oAuthService.getOAuthAccessToken(liToken, verifier);
    //SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(LINKEDIN_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE);
    // final Editor edit = settings.edit();
    // edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
    // edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
    // accessToken.getTokenSecret());
    // edit.putString("linkedin_login", "valid");
    // edit.commit();

    client = factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

    // client.postNetworkUpdate("LinkedIn Android app test");

    Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID, ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME, ProfileField.HEADLINE));

    System.out.println("First Name :: " + profile.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last Name :: " + profile.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Head Line :: " + profile.getHeadline());

    OAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(accessToken.getToken(), accessToken.getTokenSecret());

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares");
    try {
        consumer.sign(post);
        post.setHeader("content-type", "text/XML");
        String myEntity = "<share><comment>This is a test</comment><visibility><code>anyone</code></visibility></share>";
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(myEntity));
        org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
        // Get the response
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader
          (new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer strBfr = new StringBuffer();   
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

            strBfr.append(line);
        } 
        System.out.println("Response is : "+strBfr.toString());
        Toast.makeText(ShareInLinkedIn.this, strBfr.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Constants.java

```
    public class Constants {

public static final String CONSUMER_KEY = "YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY";
public static final String CONSUMER_SECRET = "YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET_KEY";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME = "x-oauthflow-linkedin";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST = "litestcalback";
public static final String OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL = OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME + "://" + OAUTH_CALLBACK_HOST;
public static final String SCOPE_PARAMS = "rw_nus+r_basicprofile";
```

}

AndroidManifiest.xml file

```
      <activity
        android:name="com.linkedin.ShareInLinkedIn"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="litestcalback"
                android:scheme="x-oauthflow-linkedin" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```